# modulo arithmetic steps for this program

Tags: c, modulus

I have written this code in `C` where each of `a,b,cc,ma,mb,mcc,N,k` are `int` . But as per specification of the problem , `N` and `k` could be as big as `10^9` . `10^9` can be stored within a `int` variable in my machine. But internal and final value of of `a,b,cc,ma,mb,mcc` will be much bigger for bigger values of `N` and `k` which can not be stored even in a `unsigned long long int` variable.

Now, I want to print value of `mcc % 1000000007` as you can see in the code. I know, some clever modulo arithmetic tricks in the operations of the body of the `for` loop can create correct output without any overflow and also can make the program time efficient. Being new in modulo arithmetic, I failed to solve this. Can someone point me out those steps?

```
ma=1;mb=0;mcc=0;
for(i=1; i<=N; ++i){
    a=ma;b=mb;cc=mcc;
    ma = k*a + 1;
    mb = k*b + k*(k-1)*a*a;
    mcc = k*cc + k*(k-1)*a*(3*b+(k-2)*a*a);
}
printf("%d\n",mcc%1000000007);
```

**My attempt:**

I used `a,b,cc,ma,mb,mcc` as `long long` and done this. Could it be optimized more ??

```
ma=1;mb=0;cc=0;
ok = k*(k-1);
for(i=1; i<=N; ++i){
    a=ma;b=mb;
    as = (a*a)%MOD;

    ma = (k*a + 1)%MOD;

    temp1 = (k*b)%MOD;
    temp2 = (as*ok)%MOD;
    mb = (temp1+temp2)%MOD;

    temp1 = (k*cc)%MOD;
    temp2 = (as*(k-2))%MOD;
    temp3 = (3*b)%MOD;
    temp2 = (temp2+temp3)%MOD;
    temp2 = (temp2*a)%MOD;
    temp2 = (ok*temp2)%MOD;
    cc = (temp1 + temp2)%MOD;
}
printf("%lld\n",cc);
```

Comment: Reall not clear for me: could you explain better your problem?

Comment: Hint: `(a + b) mod c == ((a mod c) + (b mod c)) mod c`, and similar for multiplication.

Comment: @molbdnilo, Yeah, I have tried this two properties of multiplication and additions. But, getting wrong results. Maybe applied on wrong places

Comment: @LPs, I have edited some part. please reconsider

Comment: @SurajeetBharati Post your attempt, along with your values for `k`, `N`, and the expected and actual output.

Comment: @molbdnilo, ok. I am editing

Comment: I believe that there is a Gnu Extended Integer system that you can use, which is what things like Python use to do stuff with very large numbers.

Comment: @Gophyr,  I am not allowed to use any extended system

Comment: @SurajeetBharati, your updated code does not take much advantage of molbdnilo's hint.  You are fighting with integer overflow, and you must avoid it *ever* occurring.  Additional hint: adding two `n`-digit numbers produces a number of up to `n+1` digits, and multiplying an `n`-digit number by an `m`-digit number produces a result with up to `n + m` digits.

Comment: @SurajeetBharati, consider, however, what happens when your `N` is near its upper bound.  If you have a short time limit on the computation, then performing billions of arithmetic operations is unlikely to be adequately performant.

Comment: @SurajeetBharati Then just write your own system XD  On a serious note, perhaps you could just do something like write a function to approximate the size of the number, and if it exceeds a certain size, then divide it up between two integers.  Say, one integer holding 10^0 through 10^5, and another holding 10^5 through 10^10, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at a small example:

```
mb = (k*b + k*(k-1)*a*a)%MOD;
```

Here, `k*b`, `k*(k-1)*a*a` can overflow, so can the sum, taking into account

```
(x + y) mod m = (x mod m + y mod m) mod m
```

we can rewrite this (`x= k*b`, `y=k*(k-1)*a*a` and `m=MOD`)

```
mb = ((k*b) % MOD + (k*(k-1)*a*a) %MOD) % MOD
```

now, we could go one step futher. Since

```
x * y mod m = (x mod m * y mod m) mod m
```

we can also rewrite the multiplication `k*(k-1)*a*a % MOD` with with `x=k*(k-1)` and `y=a*a` to

```
((k*(k-1)) %MOD) * ((a*a) %MOD)) % MOD
```

I'm sure you can do the rest. While you can sprinkle `% MOD` all over the place, you should careful consider whether you need it or not, taking [John's hint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30216062/modulo-arithmetic-steps-for-this-program/30218644#comment48538776_30216062) into account:

> Adding two n-digit numbers produces a number of up to n+1 digits, and
>   multiplying an n-digit number by an m-digit number produces a result
>   with up to n + m digits.

As such, there are places where you will need use modulus properties, and there are some, where you surely don't need it, but this is your part of the work ;).

Answer (score 0):

That's a good exercise to build a template class along these lines:

```
template <int N>
class modulo_int_t
{
public:
    modulo_int_t(int value) : value_(value % N) {}
    modulo_int_t<N> operator+(const modulo_int_t<N> &rhs)
    {
        return modulo_int_t<N>(value_ + rhs.value) ;
    }
    // fill in the other operations
private:
    int value_ ;
} ;
```

Then write the operations using modulo_int_t<1000000007> objects instead of int.
Disclaimer: make use of long long where appropriate and take care of negative differencies...

Comment: Um, that is C++ and the question is for C.